# Restify (Node) connection not closed after res.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

We have a Node/Restify app and I'm having a problem with this route (some code has been omitted, so please ignore missing identifiers):

```
server.post('/report', requireAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    generateReport(err, result, extension, contentType) {
        // Filename for the report
        var filename = 'Report_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD_HH:mm:ss')
        
        // Output the result directly with a lower-level APIs
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(result),
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename='+filename+'.'+extension
        })
        res.write(result, 'utf8')
        res.end()
        console.log('ended')
        
        return next()
    }
})
```

The problem is that, after sending the output, the connection with the client is not closed, even if I call res.end()! (res is just a wrapper around the standard [HTTP ServerResponse](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) module).
Commenting out `return next()` doesn't make any difference.
I can see on the console 'ended' and I know the content is sent to the client because if I force the termination of the connection (by simply terminating the Node process), the client has all the output.

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

Removing the `Content-Length` header, instead, makes it work. Why is that? (The advice to use that header is part of the [documentation](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#content-negotiation))

### EDIT2

The value of `Buffer.byteLength(result)` is 4478 bytes, but the data downloaded by the client (Postman) is 4110, and that's likely why the connection is not being closed (the client is expecting to receive more data). How is that possible?

Comment: The connection most likely kept alive by `keep-alive`. Why must connection be terminated?

Comment: It's an API server and I'm testing with Postman; there's no keep-alive. The connection must be terminated because otherwise the client is still waiting for output! (Postman doesn't display the result until the connection is terminated)